# View Delegate Building Correct SQL, Returning No Records

Tags: acumatica

I have an inquiry screen in which we filter historical AP records from a custom DAC by a VendorID or FinPeriodID from the filter.

I've created a View Delegate to handle the dynamic filtering logic, and through debugging have confirmed that it's being hit correctly and is appending the proper WhereAnd statement with the current value of the Filter. Running the SQL statement equivalent directly in the database is returning the correct records, however the View Delegate ends up returning no records to the screen.

The base view is just defined as: `public PXSelectReadonly<AAAPDoc> Docs;`

The View Delegate is defined as:

```
        protected virtual IEnumerable<AAAPDoc> docs()
        {
            AAAPHistoricalFilter filter = Filter.Current;

            PXSelectBase<AAAPDoc> cmd = new PXSelectReadonly<AAAPDoc>(this);

            if (filter.VendorID.HasValue)
            {
                cmd.WhereAnd<Where<AAAPDoc.vendorID, Equal<Current<AAAPHistoricalFilter.vendorID>>>>();
            }

            if (filter.FinPeriodID.HasValue)
            {
                cmd.WhereAnd<Where<AAAPDoc.finPeriodID, Equal<Current<AAAPHistoricalFilter.finPeriodID>>>>();
            }

            foreach (AAAPDoc record in cmd.Select())
            {
                yield return record;
            }
        }
```

Filter DAC

```
    [Serializable]
    [PXHidden]
    public class AAAPHistoricalFilter : IBqlTable
    {
        #region VendorID        
        public abstract class vendorID : BqlInt.Field<vendorID>
        {
        }
        [Vendor(IsDBField = false, DisplayName = "Vendor ID")]  
        public virtual int? VendorID { get; set; }
        #endregion

...
```

Edit: Updated with original partial Filter DAC to give context to solution

Comment: This looks good.  Perhaps try var cmd =  new PXSelect.... instead of PXSelectBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was a problem with my filter DAC.  I used the `[Vendor]` attribute with the property `IsDBField = false`.  Removing the `IsDbField` property altogether from the attribute gave me the expected results.